# Problema com UPDATE mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-update

Estou com um problema ao executar um comando UPDATE em meu Banco de Dados...

Minha tabela tem 2 colunas:
-Coluna 1: link(PK) varchar
-Coluna 2: statuz varchar

Preciso atualizar apenas o campo "statuz" da minha tabela.

> *mudar o valor de "NOVO" para "VISUALIZADO"

Segue o SQL que estou usando:

```
UPDATE toyota_base SET statuz = 'VISUALIZADO' WHERE link = '/comprar/toyota/etios/1-3-x-16v-flex-4p-manual/4-portas/2013/14102343';
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**O problema:**

O update não está funcionando...eu executo o comando, mas não surte nenhum efeito.

O output do SGBD indica que não houve erro de syntaxe e o comando foi executado, porém: 0 Row(s) Afectted

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Peço-lhes ajuda para resolver isto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desvendei o mistério!

> *Caso alguém tenha este mesmo problema, segue aqui a solução que encontrei:

**Ao invés de usar:**

```
WHERE campo = 'link';
```

**Usei:**

```
WHERE campo like '%link%';
```

Pronto!
Dessa forma a tabela foi atualizada como eu precisava.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Com esta síntaxe se corre o risco da atualizar uma  linha que não se quer. Qual o "type" da coluna LINK ?

Comment: @Motta, ptz...isso seria problema. Mas esses registros da coluna link são únicos, pois são Primary key o type é varchar...

Comment: É que exemplo passado de sua solução tudo que tiver uma string com "link" em qualquer posição seria atualizado.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado pelo esclarecimento...mas no meu caso esta opção me serviu pois o código final de cada link é único, aí não terá o problema de atualizar outras linhas...

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar

```
TRIM(CAMPO) = TRIM('VALOR')
```

Para remover os espaços em branco, lembrando que o operador "=" faz uma comparação exata e considera espaços em branco como caracter.